# convert sql script into format that can run on sqlite

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqlite, converters

I have a sql script generated by Entity framework which creates a very simple table.

```
create table [Destinations] (
    [Id] [int] not null identity,
    [Country] [nvarchar](max) null,
    [State] [nvarchar](max) null,
    [City] [nvarchar](max) null,
    primary key ([Id])
);
```

I'm trying to run this on Sqlite database, but it seems the syntax is different.
I have tried to write a replace method to replace the keywords with their sqlite version, which is not fully working. 
I was wondering if there is a better way to make these changes or if there is a library to do this in C#?

This is the converted script:

```
create table [Destinations] ( 
[Id] INTEGER not null AUTOINCREMENT , 
[Country] [nvarchar](max) null, 
[State] [nvarchar](max) null, 
[City] [nvarchar](max) null, 
primary key ([Id]) 
);
```

Comment: What is the exact error? What does your new script look like? For starters it looks like there is no nvarchar datatype in sqllite, which means your entity framework data types will probably be different which will cause issues.

Comment: That's my problem, the current script is: create table [Destinations] (
    [Id] INTEGER not null AUTOINCREMENT ,
    [Country] [nvarchar](max) null,
    [State] [nvarchar](max) null,
    [City] [nvarchar](max) null,
    primary key ([Id])
); Im trying to find a tool to automate this transformation.

Comment: I added your script to the original question. I don't know if there is a library to help, but there does not appear to be a nvarchar data type in sqllite, and I doubt you are going to be able to just point your data layer at it. Why do you need to convert to SQLLite?

Comment: How are you telling EF to use the SQLite data provider?

Comment: `primary key` is already `AUTOINCREMENT` and `not null`, they are unnecessary, remove them and then it works.

Answer (score 0):

The precise SQL you want is this:

```
create table [Destinations] ( 
[Id] integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
[Country] [nvarchar], 
[State] [nvarchar], 
[City] [nvarchar]
);
```

Changes:

1. Primary key declaration should be `integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`
2. Remove `(max)` from the type declarations
3. Remove `null` from the column declarations
4. Remove `primary key ([Id])` from the end (and the associated comma)

Note that SQLite will understand `nvarchar` fine and set the field's type affinity to `TEXT` since the type contains `CHAR` in it. See http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

**EDIT**

I previously had a comment about this not being necessary since SQLite supports EF.  The OP corrected me in stating that SQLite's implementation of EF does not support code first, hence the problem.

Comment: That's right. It supports entity framework, but it does not support code first approach. as a result I tried to get the context database creation script and then maullat run it on the sqlite database. like this: sqlScript = (context as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.CreateDatabaseScript().Replace("[dbo].", "");

Comment: @user3752903, I didn't realize it doesn't support code first. I hope the first part of my answer helps you then.